# Tag whitespace differs between first and subsequent page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, asset-pipeline, minify

I'm having a tough time even finding a point to start debugging this.  Basically, I'm setting up a copy of [Shapado](http://shapado.com/questions), a fairly normal Rails 3 app that has lots of .html.haml views like this:

```
.author
  %span
    = I18n.t('global.by_semi')
  = render :partial => "users/user_mini" ...
```

The first time I load a page on my site in production mode, all the tags in the output get crunched together:

```
<div class="author"><small><span>Asked by</span><a href="/users/jpatokal"
data-layout="user" rel="author">Jani</a>6
```

Which renders incorrectly as "Asked by[Jani](http://example.com)6".

But in development mode, and (even more oddly) also the second and subsequent times I load the same page in production mode, the tags are separated by linefeeds:

```
<div class="author">
<small>
<span>
Asked by
</span>
<a href="/users/jpatokal" data-layout="user" rel="author">Jani</a>
6
```

And since linefeeds are space in HTML, this now renders correctly: "Asked by [Jani](http://example.com) 6"

I presume this has something to do with Rails 3 asset pipelining, minification and/or caching, but as far as I can figure out the config ([see Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/shapado/shapado/trees/master/config)) does not actually pipeline Haml.  A quick looksie through a diff of config/environments/development.rb with c/e/production.rb also doesn't reveal anything obviously relevant.  Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output should not change in subsequent calls. Try to update HAML with `bundle update haml`.

You can force "ugly" mode to `false` in your `application.rb` or `production.rb`:

```
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = false
```

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options